# Program management, according to whether it was started directly or with another file by dragging its icon. (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When i start batch file by double-click, in variable %1 is `ECHO is off.` But when i start the batch file, with another file (drag&drop) to batch file icon, in variable %1 contains path to file was i started with.

I need to do this thing:
program start
when is in %1 `ECHO is off.` goto A
when is in %1 anything else, then goto B

I tried many potetial solutions for my problem, but any of thin doesn´t work.
I tried it with `find` , `findstr` and one of this with combination of `for`.
I have feeling that this is impossible in batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get `echo is off` inside `%1`. When you double click the batch file there are not arguments, so `%1` is empty and `echo %1` is parsed and converted into `echo` (no arguments, no value to echo) and when executed without parameters `echo` just shows the current `echo` status.

For a start point you can use something like

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
```

Comment: Awesome! I did not have any idea it is working like that :D. I wrote a small simple script, so I tested it and it works! Thanks! `@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
if "%~1"=="" goto nothing
echo In %1 is something.
pause
exit

:nothing
echo in %1 is nothing.
pause
exit
`